# Curvature of a curve

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, curvature

How do you find the curvature of a curve of $y=2x-x^2$ at the point where $x=1$ ?

If someone could provide me a little step by step, that would be great!

Comment: One can always start with the definitions. How do you define the curvature of $y$ at a point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$k(x)=\frac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: does that equation always hold true

Comment: @user90705 Yes, as long as the function is continuous.

Comment: and should it be the absolute value of the 2nd derivative of y

Comment: @user90705: That depends upon whether you want the signed or unsigned curvature.